# Setting rng in Scalacheck Parameters in 1.13

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Just upgraded to Scalacheck 1.13 from 1.12. In my previous code, it was possible to override the `rng` of `Test.Parameters` (via `override val rng = ..`). I then use that `Parameters` in a `check()`.

In 1.13, `rng` has been removed from `Test.Parameters`. How do I achieve what I was doing before?